# BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST IOCTL Execution

Tags: windows, driver, ioctl, kmdf

I am trying to execute [IOCTL_BTH_GET_DEVICE_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi//bthioctl/ni-bthioctl-ioctl_bth_get_device_info) for this purpose,as a beginner I write following code

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
#include <initguid.h> 
#include <ntstrsafe.h>
#include <bthdef.h>
#include <ntintsafe.h>
#include <bthguid.h>
#include <bthioctl.h>
#include <sdpnode.h>
#include <bthddi.h>
#include <bthsdpddi.h>
#include <bthsdpdef.h>
#include <wdfobject.h>
#include <wdfdriver.h>
#include <wdm.h>

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;
UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\MyDeivce123");
PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = NULL;
UNICODE_STRING SymLinkName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\mydevicelink123");
NTSTATUS BleDispatchCreate(PDEVICE_OBJECT device_obj, PIRP Irp)
{
KdPrint((" Inside BleDispatchCreate "));
KdPrint((" BleDispatchCreate Execution complete"));
//need to return status
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS BleDispatchDeviceControl(PDEVICE_OBJECT device_obj, PIRP Irp)
{
KdPrint((" Inside BleDispatchDeviceControl "));

KdPrint((" BleDispatchDeviceControl Execution complete"));
//need to return status
return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
//removed Unload function
NTSTATUS BleTest(PDEVICE_OBJECT device_obj, PIRP Irp)
{
PBTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST PBLRI = (PBTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST)Irp- >AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
PIO_STACK_LOCATION irp_sl = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
KdPrint(("Number of devices are before i/ocall  %lu", PBLRI->numOfDevices));
status = IoCallDriver(device_obj, Irp);
if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    KdPrint(("IOCALLDRIVER  SUCCESS : \n "));
    KdPrint(("Number of devices are %lu", PBLRI->numOfDevices));
}
else {
    KdPrint(("Driver call Failed!\r\n"));
    return status;
}
return status;
}
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING 
RegistryPath) {
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
int i;
DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;

status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, 
&DeviceName,FILE_DEVICE_BLUETOOTH,FILE_CHARACTERISTIC_PNP_DEVICE, FALSE, 
&DeviceObject);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
    KdPrint(("creating device failed \n "));
    return status;
}else
    KdPrint(("Device creation successful\r\n"));
status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymLinkName, &DeviceName);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
    KdPrint(("creating symbolic link failed \n"));
    IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
    return status;
}else
    KdPrint(("Symbolic link creation successful\r\n"));
DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = 
BleDispatchDeviceControl;
/********fill IRP *****************************/
PIRP Irp = NULL;
ULONG IoControlCode = IOCTL_BTH_GET_DEVICE_INFO;
ULONG InputBufferLength = sizeof(BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST);
BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST  InputBuffer;
ULONG OutputBufferLength = sizeof(BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST);
BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST  OutputBuffer;
BOOLEAN InternalDeviceIoControl = FALSE;
PKEVENT Event = NULL;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK ISB;
PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock = &ISB;
Irp = IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(IoControlCode, DeviceObject,&InputBuffer, 
InputBufferLength, &OutputBuffer, OutputBufferLength,InternalDeviceIoControl, 
Event, IoStatusBlock);
/* IO_COMPLETION_ROUTINE CdDevCtrlCompletionRoutine;
NTSTATUS
    CdDevCtrlCompletionRoutine(
        _In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
        _In_ PIRP Irp,
        _In_reads_opt_(_Inexpressible_("varies")) PVOID Contxt
    );*/
BleTest(DeviceObject, Irp);
KdPrint(("Driver LOAD ENDS returning success \n "));
return status;
}
```

Output log file is

- Device creation successful
- Symbolic link creation successful
- Number of devices are before I/O call  1313444832
- Inside BleDispatchDeviceControl
- BleDispatchDeviceControl Execution complete
- IOCALLDRIVER  SUCCESS :
- Number of devices are 1313444832
- Driver LOAD ENDS returning success
- Driver unload called

It print some garbage value in my opinion.Please point out to the mistake I made init ? I am beginner in this field.If this is post is not clear please point me.I will try to make it more consise.

Comment: Your code seems to have a lot of issues, did you try to check if the return value of `IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest` is `NULL`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the return value of `IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest`, it is not null.Could you please point me out issues I made in code,I will try to improve.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is incomplete, `DeviceObject`, `OutputBufferLength` and `device_obj` are undefined. So I have no way to test it, I will tell you the issues I see so far, but if they cannot fix the error, please make a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

1. `InputBuffer` or `OutputBuffer` currently means an array with `sizeof(BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST)` elements and the element type is `PVOID`, which is obviously wrong. They should be `BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST Input; BTH_DEVICE_INFO_LIST Output;`, and then use them this way `&Input` `&Output`. But this issue should not affect the results, they will just take up more stack space and are meaningless.
2. `\InternalDeviceIoControl` I'm not sure what the '\' means here.
3. Irp may be asynchronous, according to [the MSDN description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iobuilddeviceiocontrolrequest), if you pass `NULL` to the `Event` parameter, you must supply an [`IoCompletion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nc-wdm-io_completion_routine) routine.
4. The MSDN does not say that the `IoStatusBlock` parameter allows `NULL`, so please always pass a pointer to a variable of type `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`.
5. What is the return value of `IoCallDriver`? `STATUS_PENDING` or something else?
6. Changing `(*PBLRI).numOfDevices` to `PBLRI->numOfDevices` would be better.

The error you are facing is most likely due to point 3, so consider supplying an `IoCompletion` routine or passing an initialized `KEVENT` variable, and then waiting for the Irp to complete.

Comment: Edited question for better solution. Updated the code with your input from point 1,4&6. Tried to add `IoCompletion ` but not get success,may be I am adding in wrong way.
In response to point 5 the status of `IoCallDriver` is `STATUS_SUCCESS`

Comment: is it something very silly or childish mistake in my question that nobody answer it? if you can help me by pointing out mistake,I will be very thankful.

Comment: @robo98 No, because I have never developed any drivers about Bluetooth, I can't go on to answer this question. I have cursorily checked the code and there are probably no more obvious errors. It might be helpful to study the Bluetooth projects in [Windows-driver-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples). Good luck! :)